# PHP sessions: $_SESSION is empty running locally on Mac

Tags: php

I know there are similar other questions here, but none of them solved my problem.

**The problem:** I'm setting data into $_SESSION, but in upcoming calls it is appearing as empty.

**What I did to try solving it?**

1. Make sure to run an up-to-date version of PHP
2. Make sure to know which php.ini is used
3. Log status of $_SESSION before and after setting it
4. Set various variables as suggested in other questions and forums

Here below I provide all the info I could supply, and hoping somebody will be able to suggest a solution!

---

I have installed PHP on my Mac using `brew install php`

I am running it locally for software development using this command:

```
php -S localhost:8099 -d display_errors=on -t .
[Tue Nov 17 23:12:55 2020] PHP 7.4.11 Development Server (http://localhost:8099) started
```

I'm calling `session_start();` at the beginning of my script.
I am setting values into $_SESSION, but it is always empty when I am testing it in the following calls:

```
$ses = json_encode($_SESSION);
site_log("before: {$ses}");

session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION["upath"] = 'XXXXXX';

$ses = json_encode($_SESSION);
site_log("after: {$ses}");
```

The result is always the same (while I'm expecting to see it on first call but not for the following calls):

```
20201118_040124_484 before: []
20201118_040124_485 after: {"upath":"XXXXXX"}
```

I was trying to follow many ideas from web forums:

Verify which is the INI file:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
>Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
>Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

I was setting various INI file variables:

```
session.save_path = "/Users/myuser/Prog/MyApp/sessions"
+
chmod 777 /Users/myuser/Prog/MyApp/sessions
+
session.use_cookies = 1
+
session.cookie_secure = 0
```

But the result is still the same. Any idea please?

The following link points to the result of calling phpinfo(): [link](https://vedibarta.org/session-info.txt)

Comment: Are session files created in the session save path? Is the cookie properly set and being returned?

Comment: thanks for the comment. files are generated in the session folder? yes. Cookie is set in the browser? NO. but are cookies a must? and what if cookies are disabled in the browser, can't sessions rely on IP of the client?

Comment: No cookies, no session. That's how sessions work. If you're not using a cookie, you need to transport the session id some other way explicitly, which you're probably not doing and which isn't typically a good idea anyway. — *"can't sessions rely on IP of the client?"* – No, otherwise everyone sharing the same IP (e.g. in a large company) will share the same session.

Comment: Thanks again @deceze. I suspected so but you made it clear. Anyway why cookies are not sent? I was linking to the INI setup I'm having, and can't find what is done wrong. Maybe the problem is the communication from localhost?

Comment: There's not enough here to be able to say for sure. Make sure you're looking at your error logs…?

Comment: There aren't any logs, but I have found some interesting info here related to localhost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948217/session-cookie-not-being-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I have found a solution.

It is based on information provided here: [Session cookie not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948217/session-cookie-not-being-set)

As @deceze was commenting correctly to my question, the first steps to debug such problem are these:

1. Check whether session files are created in the save_path folder (in my case: yes)
2. Use the dev-tools of the browser to see if cookies are set for the site (in my case: no)

So the actual problem is: why cookies are not set?

#### The solution:

1. Add an entry to alias 127.0.0.1 as a 'dot com' name. This is what I did:

```
# for Mac! see linked answer for other platforms

sudo vi /private/etc/hosts 

# add this line:
127.0.0.1 mylocal.com
```

2. Activate the local php server for this domain (from the site root folder):

```
php -S mylocal.com:8099 -d display_errors=on -t .
```

3. Load the site from the php server. I'm using **Brackets**, and I had to open the menu: File -> Project Settings and set the live preview base URL to be:

```
http://mylocal.com:8099/
```

4. Some variables in the INI file might need to be set too, as already detailed in the question above

Hoping this info will help to others!